# fullPage.js auto cycle through slideshow unable to advance to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, fullpage.js

I'm working with the [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin for a simple site I am doing.

### tl;dr

What is the best way to allow a user to scroll past the slideshow while it is still cycling through the slides, so they can continue viewing the other sections of the site?

### Where my code stands now...

I have created the functionality to automatically start cycling through the different slides of the slideshow in one of my sections, based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/337) that was answered. You can see my jsFiddle linked below to see it in action.

### My Issue

The issue I am having is using this `setTimeout` to cycle through the slides automatically, if I try to then scroll (or navigate in any way) to another section of my page, the `setTimeout` keeps going and therefore I am taken back up to the slideshow as it continues to cycle. My code using the `setTimeout` looks like this:

```
afterRender: function () {
    //on page load, start the slideshow
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, 0);
    }, 1000);
},
afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if (anchorLink == 'home') {
        //make the slideshow automatically go!
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, slideIndex + 1);
        }, 1000);

        //if you are at the last slide
        //then cycle back to the first
        if (slideIndex == 2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, 0);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

### What I tried

I looked into the issue and saw [a possible solution](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/431#issuecomment-42404270) was to `clearInterval`. I figured the best time to do this would be in the [`onLeave` callback](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction).

```
onLeave: function (index, direction) {
    //after leaving section 1 (home) and going anywhere else, stop the slideshow
    if (index == '1') {
        clearInterval(slideTimeout);
    }
}
```

I set a global `slideTimeout` variable at the top of my page and then set my `setTimeout` above equal to this variable, but it does not actually seem to be doing a `clearInterval` and instead the slideshow just keeps cycling through its slides. I verified (through console.log) that when I scroll down to the next section from the slideshow, the `onLeave` callback is indeed being hit.

I'm not entirely sure `clearInterval` is my ideal solution, because I don't necessarily want the slideshow to *stop* cycling altogether (because eventually the user may return to the slideshow and I want it to keep cycling).

I have the code available here in a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/6SQhb/5/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onLeave` callback was changed time ago. Now it has 3 parameters instead of 2 as you can see [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction):

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
```

> **onLeave (index, nextIndex, direction)**
>   This callback is fired once the user leaves a section, in the transition to the new section.

[Here you have it working](http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/7/) with `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. I also used `moveSlideRight` instead of `moveTo` and I removed the `afterSlideLoad` callback which is not needed anymore.

This is the resulting code:

```
var slideTimeout;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#ccc', '#999', '#777'],
    anchors: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],
    animateAnchor: false,
    menu: '.nav',
    paddingTop: '50px',
    verticalCentered: false,
    slidesNavigation: true,
    slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
    css3: true,
    afterRender: function () {
        //on page load, start the slideshow
         slideTimeout = setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
    },


    onLeave: function (index, direction) {
        //after leaving section 1 (home) and going anywhere else, whether scrolling down to next section or clicking a nav link, this SHOULD stop the slideshow and allow you to navigate the site...but it does not
        if (index == '1') {
            console.log('on leaving the slideshow/section1');
            clearInterval(slideTimeout);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hey @Alvaro, is there currently a way to succesfully do this? And have the slider running, even after clicking a link in the menu?

Comment: @Jeroen not sure what do you mean with that. You'd better open a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

This works great to create the auto-cycle. Is it possible to pause this if a user mouses over a target element - like a div or button?